# Color visibility test failure with 1366x768 res on laptop

Tags: opengl

I'm making a simple CAD 3D graphics application using OpenGl v.1.0.1 (yes, that dummy legacy OpenGL available on on all machines using Windows OS).

To speed up the rendering process I'm using a common color visibility test: before rendering the final image I first switch off all OpenGL states (lighting, face culling etc. but not a depth test) and render all objects with slightly different colors to a texture.

After that I check the texture for the colors and finally set visibility flags to elements whose color appeared on the texture.

This normally works for me on my desktop with a default resolution of 1600x1200. But when I test my application on my laptop which has a default resolution of 1366x768 I get some mismatches in that process. The result is that the final image always is drawn with a "scar" (it's like a strip where color bits which normally pass visibility test on a desktop do not pass it on the laptop).

What can cause such a problem?

Updated. Two images to illustrate the problem: [1360x768 res (desktop)](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/855/1360.png/) and [1366x768 res (laptop)](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/560/1366e.png/)

Updated. The source code of method where I reading the bitfield and converting color appeared on texture to number of the element I should render:

```
for (long iY = m_iColorBuffY - viewport[3]; iY < m_iColorBuffY; ++iY) {
    for (long iX = 0; iX < viewport[2]; ++iX) {
        long iOffset = (iY*m_iColorBuffX + iX)*iColorBytes;
        long CurColor = 0;
        for (long iColorByte = 0; iColorByte < iColorBytes; ++iColorByte) {     
            BYTE color = *((BYTE*)m_pColorBufferEntry + iOffset + iColorByte);  
            CurColor += (color<<(iColorBytes - 1 - iColorByte)*8);
        }
        if(!CurColor) continue;
        long Index = CModelWorldRenderer::ConvertFictiveColorToIndex(mc,CurColor);
        switch (mc) {
         case MC_FE: {
          IElement^ pCurElement = pModel->getElement(Index);
          if (pCurElement) pCurElement->setFlag(IElement::e_ElFlag::EEF_Visible);
          m_pObjectsVisibilityMap->put_ObjectIndex(
              false,
              Index,
              iX,
              viewport[3] - (iY - viewport[1] + 1));
         }
         break;
         case MC_NODE: {
          if (Index < ndSize) m_NodesVisibilityFlags[Index] |= NRF_VISIBLE;
         }
         break;
        }
    }
```

*m_pColorBufferEntry - pointer to the beginning of memory allocated for the bitmap.

Comment: Wild guess, `float` operations.

Comment: How do you create the "slightly different colors"?

Comment: I have all my object listed in one container, so objects getting their colors based on their number in list.

Comment: @RomanGomolyako I understand, but _how exactly_ do you compute them? Some source code could possibly help! Apart from that, what texture format are you using? And how do you test the equality of your colors? A simple `==` might not be sufficient for comparing `float` values, as Shahbaz suggested.

Comment: @kroneml Before actually start rendering to detect visibility I'm changing OpenGL context providing bitmap descriptor as HDC.